# How to move composer dependency from require-dev to require?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have two projects on my git repo server. The first one is a library I wrote, let's call it `foo/lib-bar`. The second is an application which uses that library `foo/app-bar`. Currently the library is in development version, so the `composer.json` file of the library looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "foo/lib-bar",
    "description": "Bar library",
    "version": "1.0.0-dev",
    "type": "library",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4",
        "ext-posix": "*"
    }
}
```

The application uses this library, so it contains the necessary requirement:

```
{
    "name": "foo/app-bar",
    "description": "Bar application",
    "version": "0.5.0-dev",
    "type": "application",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "ssh://user@git.example.com/lib-foo"
        }
    ],
    "require-dev": {
        "foo/lib-bar": ">=1.0.0-dev",
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.3"
    }
}
```

And everything is smooth up to this point: both `composer install` and `composer update` run as expected, install the dependency and I can see it in `vendor/`

Now, [the docs](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#require) says that

```
require#

Lists packages required by this package. The package will not be installed unless those requirements can be met.
```

**And for the steps which lead to the issue in question**:

So ok, my library is ready to be deployed and come out of the development phase. It also happens to be required in production version of my application. I remove the `dev` suffix from the `composer.json` file of my *library*, commit and push the file, and am ready to update the application.

With the application's `composer.json` I move the library dependency from `require-dev` section to `require` and remove the `dev` suffix (everything is copy-pasted, so there is no typo - I've checked and rechecked again):

```
    "require-dev": {},
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.3",
        "foo/lib-bar": ">=1.0.0"
    }
```

Now I run `composer update` and I get:

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)                     
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for foo/lib-bar >=1.0.0 -> satisfiable by foo/lib-bar[dev-master].
    - Removal request for foo/lib-bar == 9999999-dev
```

I assumed it did not find the new version, so I deleted the old library manually:

```
$ rm composer.lock
$ rm -rf vendor/foo/
```

and tried to install it from scratch

```
$ composer install
```

but this time it gives me:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package foo/lib-bar could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

So it seems like **`require-dev` does work, but `require` doesn't**. Any suggestions on what may have gone wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require-dev` is not the place to develop dependencies. It is meant for software that is used only in development, like PHPUnit, Mockery etc., or for dependencies that are useful by themselves, but in this case only used for development, like the client library for the service a software package is about (to make some real requests in a test scenario).

So your library shouldn't have been "require-dev" from the beginning.

Another thing is: Composer will deduct the version if **use appropriate branches and tags**, i.e. a branch named "1.0.x" in your repository will be detected as being the development branch for all 1.0 versions, and any requirements for such versions could possibly be satisfied by this branch - provided you allow for development versions either by setting `"minimum-stability": "dev"` (which would allow development versions for ALL software - rather unintended), or when you require version `"1.0.0@dev"` for your software.

The one thing that might currently break your composer setup is that you mention a version in the librarys composer.json explicitly, and this is a development version. Have you removed that version indicator? You should remove it, because life is easier if Composer can detect the versions from the tags in a repository, not by having them explicitly mentioned in composer.json.

Finally please make sure that when using Git you **tag the commit** with appropriate version. The `require`d version should correspond to the git tagged version.

Comment: Fair point: the `require-dev` should not have been there from the beginning, but I used it since Composer only worked with this one. I alos noticed that many libraries out there put lot's of stuff into the `require-dev` if they are of VCS. Only dependencies available on Packagist are used in `require`, so people might have the same problem as I do. As for the tagging: I figured that composer would check branches, so I made a `1.0.0` branch and it still didn't work. I did not think of **tagging commits** - my mistake (or missing documentation?). And I think that this is the **holy grail** here.

Comment: Removing the version indicator would probably do, but I **really** don't want to do this, since this is what I want: to point Composer to a specific version which I requrest. Composer can detect the version from the repository, but I want to point which version I need. Isn't this the purpose of the version field in `composer.json`?

Comment: If you include the `"version": "1.0.0"` in your library's composer.json, and also tag this, you create conflicting information for Composer. It doesn't conflict if the tag also is "1.0.0", but this static information in the composer.json will be forgotten to update when tagging a new version. Don't use it, Composer works perfect with only having a version in the tag.

Comment: Regarding stuff in "require-dev" vs. "require": Everything mentioned in a libraries "require" will be installed if you use that library. Anything in "require-dev" will NEVER be installed, because that stuff is intended to develop that library. The same applies to any further level of inclusion, i.e. included libraries.

Comment: Yep, tagging the version did the trick. Are you somehow associated with the Composer dev team? This should be mentioned in documentation.

Comment: You could create an issue in the Github issue tracker if you find the documentation not descriptive enough. It'd be not the same if I did it for you (and I am not associated with the development team, I just happen to answer a lot of these questions here).